# How Set Multi Texboxfor Values To 1 Textbox (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.textboxfor

I have 2 TextBoxFor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)  //Name
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Surname)  //Surname
```

I want to combine these two textboxfor values in 1 textbox:

```
@Html.TextBox(... or    //Name surname
input type="text" ...
```

Thanks.

Comment: That would be pointless because it wont bind to any property in you model. You would need a property like `public string FullName { get; set; }`

Comment: Pleasure, but you have accepted an answer that wont work, or at least wont post back since the property has no setter. It not really clear what your trying to achieve with this.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But already i wanted to just show this data, not to post. As I understand your solution, i need a new column 'FullName' for post, true?

Comment: _"but already i wanted to"_? Wanted to do what?

Comment: I wanted to 'show' data (only get) :) I was not going to post.
But for post, i need a new column and new property?

Comment: If it's for display only (no post) then that's OK, but no real need for a `textbox` - you could just display it in a `<div>`. But what happens when the user edits `Surname`? Your going to need some javascript to update the `FullName`. As I said before, It not really clear what your trying to achieve.

Comment: I didn't try to edit, but as you said it will not post. To achieve post, is there any solution except javascript?

Comment: If your posting `FirstName` and `Surname`, why not just construct `FullName` in the controller (as in `string fullName = FirstName + ' ' + Surname;` But I'm not sure what your wanting to do here so I can give you an answer

Comment: I have 2 column in table Name and Surname. I want to edit these columns in 1 textbox. In Arvind solution, i can only get.

Comment: As I noted in my first comment you need `public string FullName { get; set; }` but when this posts back you would need to parse the value to get the `FirstName` and `Surname` properties so you can store it in he database (e.g. using `String.Split()`) but what if the user enters "John Newton Jones"? Is their surname "Jones" or "Newton Jones"? I think you should just stick with 2 textboxes - one for each property

Comment: this is better one, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create property in your model named as FullName

```
public string FullName
{
    get
    {
        return String.Format(Name + " " + Surname);
    }
}
```

And then use FullName in TextBoxFor helper,

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FullName)
```